# Explain this inconsistency

Tags: python, mutability

Here are two methods. One modifies the variable x, the other does not. Can you please explain to me why this is?

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
def switch(a,b,x):
     x[a], x[b] = x[b], x[a]
switch(0,1,x)
print(x)
[2,1,3,4]


def swatch(x):
    x = [0,0,0,0]

swatch(x)
print(x)
[2,1,3,4]
```

Answer (score 3):

The function definition

```
def swatch(x):
```

defines `x` to be a *local* variable.

```
x = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

reassigns the local variable `x` to a new list.
This does not affect the global variable `x` of the same name.

---

You could remove `x` from the arguments of `swatch`:

```
def swatch():
    x = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but when Python encounters an assignment inside a function definition like

```
x = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Python will consider `x` a *local variable* by default. Assigning values to this `x` will not affect the global variable, `x`.

To tell Python that you wish `x` to be the global variable, you would need to use the `global` declaration:

```
def swatch():
    global x
    x = [0,0,0,0]
swatch()
```

---

However, in this case, since `x` is [mutable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types), you could define `swatch` like this:

```
def swatch(x):
    x[:] = [0,0,0,0]
```

Although `x` inside `swatch` is a local variable, since `swatch` was called with

```
swatch(x)  # the global variable x
```

it points to the same list as the global variable of the same name.

`x[:] = ...` alters the *contents* of `x`, while `x` still points to the original list. Thus, this alters the *value* that the global variable `x` points to too.

---

```
def switch(a,b,x):
     x[a], x[b] = x[b], x[a]
```

is another example where the contents of `x` are mutated while `x` still points to the original list. Thus mutating the local `x` alters the global `x` as well.